# Turn based multiplayer game with Game center

Tags: iphone, game-center

I would like to know if game center supports online turn based multiplayer game through 3G network or different wifi access. From what I have been reading so far, game center supports bluetooth and local wifi.

In addition, since I would like to implement a turn based multiplayer game, does game center support active running games such that I can play the same game with several friends at the same time like how the app Words with Friends does.

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 3):

If you can wait for iOS 5, it looks like Apple will be adding this feature to Game Center!

Answer (score 2):

You would need a server to play games like words with friends..

And you can only do a one-time connection per game.. Up to 4 players each time, unless you have a server then up to 16 players..

online turn based games is possible but not games like words with friends..